# Не читает поля из файла XML

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

К тегу <Ид> не возможно обратится, скорее всего из-за кириллицы. Как можно исправить проблему или ее тут нет и мне нужно отдохнуть?

```
<?php
include 'unicode.inc';

$xml_file = 'test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
$xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>



// Приводим значения полей тега <Ид> к числовым значениям
$ids = [];
foreach ($xml->('Ид')  as $id) {
    $numeric_id = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', ' ', $id);
    $id[0] = intval($numeric_id);
    $ids[] = $id;
}

// Сохраняем изменения в новом файле
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$output_file = "test-$date.xml";
$xml->asXML($output_file);

echo "Файл $output_file успешно создан\n";
?>
```

Comment: вангую,- не смотря на декларацию кодировки в хмл ютф, скорее всего она в вин1251, пробуй либо вывести все теги, либо принудительно сменить кодировку в загружаемом хмл.

Comment: вы уверены, что там скобки круглые а не фигурные должны быть?